# Check if some one field is empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

in my Excel document I have 51 fields that I need to check that these fields were not empty/ I am using Excel 2003 and there is maximum 30 argument of function `OR`:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A3)=TRUE;ISBLANK(B3)=TRUE...);"Some empty field";"")
```

Here is my exemple, but I need to check more fields, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `COUNTA`, ie for 51 cells from `A3` to `AY3`

```
=IF(COUNTA(A3:AY3)=51,"ok",51-COUNTA(A3:AY3) & "fields are empty")
```

*footnote: `=ISBLANK(A3)` is the same as `=ISBLANK(A3)=TRUE` but is simpler*

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, the best is the option 4 below

Couple of options:

1. VBA
2. insert a row 4 (you will hide it afterwards) and put there these formulas:

   A4: =IsBlank(A3)
   B4: =OR(A4, IsBlank(B3))
   and copy this formula further on, e.g. C4: =OR(B4, IsBlank(C3)), ... then, in the last cell you will have the answer
3. If you know that the cells should contain numbers of if this just works for you, the formula would be =(A3+0)*(B3+0) .. and you test if the result is 0. The blank plus 0 is 0
4. **Possibly best would be for you to use this:=NOT(ISBLANK(A1))+0 and then multiply the results. ISBLANK + 0 converts the true to 1, that is =IF(NOT((ISBLANK(A3))+0) * (NOT(ISBLANK(b3))+0) ... =0, xxxxx**

Comment: thanks, this can be useful, but in my case I use a table, so I will have a lot of extra rows

Comment: Use VBA - see this link http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/91624-visual-basic-applications-isempty-loop.html, or extra blank sheet (you can hide this)

Comment: There is one more trick you can use - see the modified answer

Comment: No need for anything so complicated.  @brettdj has the answer.

Comment: Yes, that solution works well. The (4) option is however easiest to use if you want to generalize blanks to blanks or certain text.